# Decimal is printing wrong when int 1 is input

Tags: java

Can someone please point out why my decimal input of 1 does not transfer to the output. Meaning if I enter 1 when prompted for integer it spits out everything correct except my decimal. The decimal comes out to 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dboh {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        int single;
        int val;
        int rem;

        //Binary
        String binaryString = "";
        int value = decimal;
        while (value != 0) {
        binaryString = value % 2 + binaryString;
        value = value / 2;
        }

        //Octal
        String octalString = "";
        for(val = decimal; val > 0; val = val / 8){
            octalString = val % 8 + octalString;
            } 

         //Hexadecimal

         String hexstring=""; 

         // Digits in hexadecimal number system
         char hex[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

         do {

           rem=decimal%16; 
           hexstring=hex[rem]+hexstring; 
           decimal=decimal/16;

         }while (decimal > 0);

        System.out.println("Decimal" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" +"Binary" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "Octal" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "Hexadecimal");
        System.out.println(decimal + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + binaryString + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + octalString + "\t" +"\t" + "\t" + hexstring);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have a while loop which divides 'decimal' until it reaches 0. If you want to make use of the value of decimal without actually affecting it, consider making a copy variable.

This part

```
do {

       rem=decimal%16; 
       hexstring=hex[rem]+hexstring; 
       decimal=decimal/16;

     }while (decimal > 0);
```

Can be done perhaps with this:

```
int dec = decimal;
do {

       rem=decimal%16; 
       hexstring=hex[rem]+hexstring; 
       dec/= 16;

     }while (dec> 0);
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, Thank you so much. I tried something very close to that but was getting an error from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a local variable `float result` like this:

```
    int decimal = input.nextInt();
    float result;
```

And cast the decimal to float like this:

```
       result=(float)decimal/16;
```

And change the while loop like this:

```
     }while (result < 0);
```

And the sysout like this:

```
    System.out.println(result + "...
```

Got output :

```
  Decimal           Binary          Octal           Hexadecimal
  0.0625            1           1           1
```